# Width of container is not setting properly using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my flexbox container to be of same width as the above one, but whenever I am adding a left/right padding to the container it increases the width. Let me know how do I handle padding in flexbox.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body{ box-sizing: border: box; width: 100%; }

.container { padding: 20px; }

.container.flex { 
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* Adding Padding left and right 20px is adding a scroller */
  gap: 20px;
}

.container.flex .box { flex-basis: 100%; }

.one { background: #80558C; }
.two { background: #AF7AB3; }
.three { background: #CBA0AE; }
.four { background: #E4D192; }
.five { background: #576F72; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>

<div class="container flex">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the container width and the starting position of my flex container, I have added a `margin-left: 20px` which shift the container to the left by 20px.

Now to have a space from the right, I adjusted the width of the container, like - `width: calc(100% - 40px);`.

Working Code -

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border: box; }
html, body{ width: 100%; }

.container { padding: 20px; }

.container.flex { 
  display: flex; 
  width: calc(100% - 40px); 
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
}

.container.flex .box { flex-basis: 100%; text-align: center; }

.one { background: #80558C; }
.two { background: #AF7AB3; }
.three { background: #CBA0AE; }
.four { background: #E4D192; }
.five { background: #576F72; }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>

<div class="container flex">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just reduce the width by the amount of padding you added, or the simpler way of adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to that flexbox.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body{ box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; }

.container { padding: 20px; }

.container.flex { 
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Adding Padding left and right 20px is adding a scroller */
  gap: 20px;
}

.container.flex .box { flex-basis: 100%; }

.one { background: #80558C; }
.two { background: #AF7AB3; }
.three { background: #CBA0AE; }
.four { background: #E4D192; }
.five { background: #576F72; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>

<div class="container flex">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I want my flexbox container to be of same width as the above one"

Comment: And what do you want to do? reduce the padding, or reduce the width of the inner elements?

Comment: I want the red box to have a width as same as the above box and should start from where the above box started and ends where the above container ends horizontally like a padding added to the flex container.

Comment: You'll either have to reduce your padding or the width of those inner elements. A two meter rope and a one meter rope will never be the same length until you cut off a meter of the two meter rope

Comment: instead of padding, I used margin to adjust the left alignment and to match the right alignment I adjusted the width. Posted my fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

adding box-sizing will fix the issue.

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
html, body{ }

.container { padding: 20px; }

.container.flex { 
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* Adding Padding left and right 20px is adding a scroller */
  gap: 20px;
}

.container.flex .box { flex-basis: 100%; }

.one { background: #80558C; }
.two { background: #AF7AB3; }
.three { background: #CBA0AE; }
.four { background: #E4D192; }
.five { background: #576F72; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>

<div class="container flex">
  <div class="box one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box four">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box five">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I want my flexbox container to be of same width as the above one"